# Use Keys, values in one dict to get values in another dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I have the following dictionary

`names= 'bob julian tim martin rod sara joyce nick beverly kevin'.split()
ids = range(len(names))
users = dict(zip(ids, names))`

so the results is

```
{0: 'bob', 1: 'julian', 2: 'tim', 3: 'martin', 4: 'rod', 5: 'sara', 6: 'joyce', 7: 'nick', 8: 'beverly', 9: 'kevin'}
```

I have another default dict called new_dict with the following

```
{5: [6, 7, 9]}
```

Ultimately I am trying to use keys and values from new_dict to pull the values from the users dict to place it in a final_dict that looks like this

```
{sara: [joyce, nick, kevin]}
```

The issue is it is saying that the dict is unhashable so code like this does not work.  How can you use keys, value in one dict to get the values in another one?

```
users[new_dict.keys()]
```

but when you do this `users[5]` this will return sara like I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there's a simpler way to define `users`:

```
users = dict(enumerate(names))
```

Your desired dict can be defined with

```
{users[name]: [users[friend] for friend in friends] for name, friends in new_dict.items()}
```

First, you iterate over the key/values pairs in `new_dict`. Both the key and its associated values are used as keys in `user`.

There's a slightly shorter way to write this, using `operator.itemgetter`.

```
from operator import itemgetter

{users[k]: list(itemgetter(*v)(users)) for k, v in new_dict.items()}
```

`itemgetter` creates a function which performs a look up on its argument using each of the arguments to `itemgetter` as keys, returning the results as a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for this, considering you want the result in a list..

```
a = {0: 'bob', 1: 'julian', 2: 'tim', 3: 'martin', 4: 'rod', 5: 'sara', 6: 'joyce', 7: 'nick', 8: 'beverly', 9: 'kevin'}
b = {5: [6, 7, 9]}
res = [{a[k]: [a[k2] for k2 in b[k]]} for k in b]
```

Result:

```
[{'sara': ['joyce', 'nick', 'kevin']}]
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `keys` (`for k in b` behaves identically).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this in a more friendly way than the rest of the answers so you can understand it better.

```
users = {0: 'bob', 1: 'julian', 2: 'tim', 3: 'martin', 4: 'rod', 5: 'sara', 6: 'joyce', 7: 'nick', 8: 'beverly', 9: 'kevin'}
new_dict = {5: [6, 7, 9]}
new_users = {}

for key in new_dict.keys():
    temp_users = []

    for value in new_dict[key]:
        temp_users.append(users[value])

    new_users[users[key]] = temp_users
```

The output of this is: `{'sara': ['joyce', 'nick', 'kevin']}`

What it does is it iterates over every key in `new_dict` which in turn iterates over its values and creates a list from them. At the end it assigns that list to the value of that specific key.

Your answer was wrong because `new_dict.keys()` returns a `<class 'dict_keys'>` and you can't just shove it and get all the values.